# Table join is so slow!

Tags: mysql, join

I have joining two tables,There are hundreds of records in table a and there are hundred thousands records in table b.I joined them both inner and left join but it is two slow.My query is:

```
SELECT 
    ch.id,
    ch.client_client_id,
    ch.duration,
    ch.start,
    ch.isread,
    ch.prefix,
    ucr.ucr_add_factor,
    ucr.ucr_period,
    ucr.ucr_cr_prefix 
FROM 
    call_history AS ch 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_usr_call_rates AS ucr 
        ON (
            ch.prefix=ucr.ucr_cr_prefix 
            AND ch.client_client_id=ucr.ucr_callshop_id
        ) 
WHERE 
    ch.isread='0'
```

How can i increase performance

Thanks for advance...

Comment: Do you have indexes on the tables for the columns on which you are joining them?

Comment: Young people today have no concept of history.  I remember when a join meant that you had to go to two separate file cabinets and match pieces of paper.  Why, you were lucky if you could get your joins done in a week.

Comment: How much time is this taking?  How much time do you want it to take?  Is this in myISAM, or InnoDB?  What else is going on in the data base?  (are there continual inserts to call_history)? This is probably going to generate a very large result set, and the speed of the query will be dependent on how fast you process the result set.   Do, please, put an index on call_history.isread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the used indexes. You can see which are used by call

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
ch.id, ch.client_client_id, ch.duration, ch.start, ch.isread, ch.prefix, 
ucr.ucr_add_factor, ucr.ucr_period, ucr.ucr_cr_prefix
FROM call_history AS ch 
LEFT JOIN tbl_usr_call_rates AS ucr
ON (ch.prefix=ucr.ucr_cr_prefix AND ch.client_client_id=ucr.ucr_callshop_id)
WHERE ch.isread='0'
```

Comment: could yo provive the result if EXPLAIN...?

Comment: in the explain output the "extra" column has "using index"

Comment: Did you need a LEFT JOIN or can you use a INNER JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

the usual suspects:

check the indexes
check that the joins don't require more than one field or you'll have a cartesian product

there are many others but these are the main ones.

jim

Answer (score 0):

I take it you have indexes on these fields?

```
call_history.prefix
tbl_usr_call_rates.ucr_cr_prefix
call_history.client_client_id
tbl_usr_call_rates.ucr_callshop_id
call_history.isread
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try by adding an index on the columns your joining on.

Answer (score 0):

Filter first via the WHERE Clause before you join, this Way you join the already filtered Result instead of Joining all of them and then filtering the big Result.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the optimizer doesn't take care of this for you.